# Why duplicates are save even if I use compound index? Mongo(Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to save click coordinates on database but if x and y are the same I don't want to save them. Even if I use compound index and do everything by book, it still saves everything. There is similar question on stackoverflow but it doesn't work for my code.

Model, Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var integerValidator = require('mongoose-integer');
var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;

var clickPoint = new Schema({
    clicks: [
         {
            x: {
                type: SchemaTypes.Double
            },
            y: {
                type: SchemaTypes.Double
            },
            value: {
                type: Number,
                integer: true
            }
        }
    ]
});

clickPoint.index({x: 1, y: 1}, {unique: true});

clickPoint.plugin(integerValidator);  
clickPoint.plugin(uniqueValidator);

//export model...
module.exports = mongoose.model("ClickPoint", clickPoint);
```

Model Controller:

```
var ClickPoint = require('../Models/point');

exports.addPoint = function (click) {
    ClickPoint.findOne(function (err, data) {
        if(!err) {
            if(data) {
                data.clicks.push({
                    x: click.x,
                    y: click.y,
                    value: click.value
                });
                data.save();
            }
            else {
                var entry = new ClickPoint({
                    x: click.x,
                    y: click.y,
                    value: click.value
                });

                entry.save();
            }
        }
    })
};
```

Could it be that all the records are stored in an array and as far as I know, index allows to store duplicates in array?  If that is the problem than how would I keep objects unique in an array.

Comment: Could it be that all the records are stored in an array and as far as I know, index allows to store duplicates in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You index `x` & `y`, while the fields are `clicks.x` & `clicks.y`. If you're trying to add unique values to an array, why not use [`addToSet`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.addToSet)?

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Do you know how to call a function in case if value already exists?